# Fetching contacts from gmail -closed

Tags: java, gmail, google-contacts-api

I am trying to fetch contacts of **gmail** using

> Google Contacts API

and

> Oauth 2.0 API.

I am totally new to this concept. I was trying the same code given in the [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) link to fetch all the contacts but somehow it won't work.

My code

```
ContactsService service = new ContactsService("<var>Contacts
Fetcher</var>"); // Exception on this line 
    public ContactsService authenticateId() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            service.setUserCredentials("example@gmail.com", "123456"); 
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        return service; 
    }
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
    at javamails.ContactsFetcher.<init>(ContactsFetcher.java:25)
    at javamails.ContactsFetcher.main(ContactsFetcher.java:68)
```

I tried to read the references and documentation given by the google but it seems not much helpful for me. If anyone has a simple example or another api to fetch the gmail contacts please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the required dependencies of the libraries you use at runtime. It seems you forgot to include the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library. Therefor the `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf` method (that is defined in that library) cannot be found.

If you tell us more about how you compile and run your code, we could tell you what setting to change.

Comment: Nothing happened the same exception is occurred again :(

Comment: a) Can you call an other method from the Guava library? b) the `copyOf` method was added in Guava 3.0. Maybe you use an outdated version of Guava?

Comment: It was clashing of all the jar files which I imported for my project. Thanks for your answer